# Error en el ClassCastException

Tags: java

El siguiente código, me da un error en la la línea 329. EL error es Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class clases.PlayList (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clases.PlayList is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Entiendo que me salga el error del ClassCastException, pero es que no se como solucionarlo. ¿Alguien sabe como solventarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
/**
 * Mostrar las playlist. Solamente quiero saber el nombre
 */
final JList listaPlaylist = new JList();
listaPlaylist.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
DefaultListModel modeloListaPlaylist = new DefaultListModel();
listaPlaylist.setModel(modeloListaPlaylist);

/*ArrayList<PlayList> playlistUsuario=null;
for (PlayList playList : playlistUsuario) {
    modeloListaPlaylist.addElement(playList+"\n");
}*/
try {
    ArrayList<PlayList> playlistUsuario = ventana.usuarioLogueado.getBiblioteca();
    for (PlayList playList : playlistUsuario) {
        modeloListaPlaylist.addElement(playList.getNombre());
    }
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Código correspondiente con el método de mostrar todas las canciones de una playlist

```
/**
         * Mostrar todas las canciones que tiene una playlist al hacer click sobre una de ellas
         */
        //Jlist donde se mostrarán todas las canciones de una playlist
        final JList listaListarCanciones = new JList();
        
        //Click en un elemento de una playlist
        listaPlaylist.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Object listaSeleccionada=(PlayList) listaPlaylist.getSelectedValue();//elementos del JList
                labelPlaylistSeleccionada.setText(listaSeleccionada.toString());//en el label, muestro el nombre de la playlist Seleccionada
            
                //cuando haga click en una playlist
                DefaultListModel cancionesModelo = new DefaultListModel();
                listaListarCanciones.setModel(cancionesModelo);//añado el modelo al Jlist
                ArrayList<Cancion> todasCanciones=(ArrayList<Cancion>) ((PlayList) listaSeleccionada).getCancionesPlayList();//devuelve un arraylist
                //System.out.println(String.valueOf(sampleObject));

                for (Cancion cancion : todasCanciones) {
                    System.out.println("Cancion ---> "+cancion);
                    cancionesModelo.addElement(cancion);//añado las canciones al modelo
                }
                panelListarCancionesPlaylist.add(listaListarCanciones);//añado la lista, con las canciones, al panel
            }

        });
```

Este último metodo, de la clase Playlist, utiliza una tabla intermedia de la bd para listar las canciones. En la bd funciona todo perfectamente.

```
/**
     * Método que devuelve todas las canciones de una playlist
     * @param listaPlayList nombre de la playlis
     * @return canciones de una playlist
     */
    public ArrayList<Cancion> getCancionesPlayList(){
        ArrayList<Cancion> canciones= new ArrayList<Cancion>();
        Statement smt = ConexionBD.conectar();
        try {
            ResultSet cursor = smt.executeQuery("select cancion.foto, cancion.nombre, artista.nombre, "
                    + "cancion.estilocancion, cancion.fechaincorporacion"
                    + "from almacenacanciones "
                    + "join playlist on almacenacanciones.playlist_nombre = playlist.nombre"
                    + "join cancion on almacenacanciones.cancion_nombre = cancion.nombre"
                    + "join artista on cancion.artista_email = artista.email"
                    + "where almacenacanciones.playlist_nombre ='"+this.getNombre()+"'");
            while(cursor.next()) {
                Cancion cancion = new Cancion();
                Artista artista = new Artista();
                cancion.setFoto(cursor.getString("cancion.foto"));
                cancion.setNombre(cursor.getString("cancion.nombre"));
                cancion.artista=new Artista(cursor.getString("artista.nombre"));
                //cancion.estiloCancion = new Estilos(cursor.getString("cancion.estilocancion"));
                cancion.estiloCancion = Estilos.valueOf(cursor.getString("cancion.estilocancion"));
                cancion.fechaIncorporacion=cursor.getTimestamp("cancion.fechaincorporacion").toLocalDateTime();
                canciones.add(cancion);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ContraseñaIncorrectaException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ConexionBD.desconectar();
        return canciones;
        
    }
```

Comment: El código insertado como imagen, no nos permite reproducir el problema, podrías pegarlo como código? Y en este caso, tampoco podemos ver cual es la línea 329 que genera la excepción. Gracias

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código

Comment: El código debe ir como edición de la pregunta. Lo que acabás de agregar es una no-respuesta.

Comment: en qué linea te da exáctamente el error, no me digas el número plis, dime el código de esa linea, he visto algo raro en tu código y quiero asegurarme de que es esa linea